# Getting "Authentication credentials were not provided." message when trying to access my ModelViewSet URL

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am creating an application using Django Rest Framework and using Token based authentication. I have a `PlaceViewSet` class inheriting from `ModelViewSet`. I want both list and retrieve to work even if there is no token sent by the user whereas create, destroy and update should be allowed only if the user has sent the Token. But I am getting `Authentication credentials were not provided.` for requests of all types. I also want to stick to the REST standard so that the list, retrieve, update, create, destroy comes under the same model view set.
In case if DRF does not allow any requests without Token if I have set my default authentication as `TokenAuthentication` then why I am able to access the signin and signup views?

Comment: also add code, which you have implemented and not working

Answer (score -1):

You can change permission policy in settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'
    ],
}
```

If you want to add special permissions for methods.

Permission:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, IsAdminUser    

class SpecialPermissionMixin(object):

    def get_permissions(self):

        user_permission_list = ['list', 'retrieve', 'update']
        admin_permission_list = ['destroy', 'create']

        if self.action in user_permission_list:

            permission_classes = [
                IsAuthenticated,
            ]
        elif self.action in admin_permission_list:

            permission_classes = [
                IsAdminUser,
            ]
        else:
            permission_classes = []

        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]
```

View:

```
class BlogViewSet(SpecialPermissionMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
      ...
```